# Where do I find (free) fully-internationalized themes?

Tags: themes, translation

I'm trying to find a theme which is fully internationalized. I've perused the list of translation-ready themes in the theme gallery, but each one seems to be missing some little detail here and there.

The only really, really fully translated theme seems to be Twenty Ten. Not that I dislike it too much, but there's a lot of redundancy and duplication in the CSS, so even simple customization is a great pain. I've already been there, and I'm not very eager to go back.

So, are there any other options available? Where do I find fully-internationalized themes?

EDIT: More specifically, I need themes with a full French translation already available.

Comment: Check out [Codium & Codium Extend](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/profile/riri23) - apparently fully French translated (I would expect just as much from a French author!)

Answer (score 2):

check out the automattic themes svn repository which holds about 108 that all should be internationalization (big word) ready

https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/

Comment: I had a look, and I saw in there themes that are not fully translated. I'm not searching for themes that are fully translatable, but for themes that are already fully translated.

Comment: I know and i understand but i mentioned it any cause i can't really say that you will find such themes,  and i just figured that you did not specify in what language do you want the themes to be